# Proper use of Web Font Loader active/inactive callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback, webfont-loader

I'm having trouble with what should be a fairly obvious question.

The Webfont Loader documentation states to place it as "the first element in the `<head>` of your HTML document."  It also includes active/inactive callback options, which are called either when the fonts are loaded or when they fail to load / time out.

The problem is, if I place my callback functions in a script block immediately after the , the callback functions are undefined at that time.

My code is as follows:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    WebFontConfig = {
      google: { families: [ 'Playball::latin' ] },
      active: doActive(),
      inactive: doInactive()
    };
    (function() {
      var wf = document.createElement('script');
      wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
      wf.type = 'text/javascript';
      wf.async = 'true';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    })(); </script>

  // ... other code ...

  <script>
    function doActive() {
        // ...
    }
    function doInactive() {
        // ...
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

That's just the default Google code, plus the two callbacks.

The only obvious option I see is to include the webfont loader after I define the other functions, but that's not elegant.  I know there is a better solution, but my Google-fu isn't finding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fault was to execute the callbacks directly.

```
 WebFontConfig = {
  google: { families: [ 'Playball::latin' ] },
  active: doActive(), // () executes directly
  inactive: doInactive()
};
```

Instead of this your should try that:

```
 WebFontConfig = {
  google: { families: [ 'Playball::latin' ] },
  active: doActive, // Only the function. The library will execute the function 
  inactive: doInactive
};
```

If the library execute your callbacks, the function should available

Comment: Thanks, this is the right answer, didn't fully understand how that was supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is looking for an answer, this is not the most elegant (or correct) method, I'm sure, but this works.

```
  <script>
    var fontsLoaded = false;
    WebFontConfig = {
      google: { families: [ 'Playball::latin' ] },
      active: function() { fontsLoaded = true },
      inactive: function() { fontsLoaded = -1 }
    };
    (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
          '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })(); </script>

// ... other stuff ...

  <script>
    var MAX_WAIT = 15000; var startTime = Date.now(); var tx;
    checkLoaded();
    function checkLoaded() {
      clearTimeout(tx);
      if (fontsLoaded === -1) { doInactive(); }
      else if (fontsLoaded) { doActive(); }
      else {
        if (Date.now()-startTime > MAX_WAIT) { doInactive(); }
        else { tx = setTimeout(checkLoaded,100); }
      }
    }
  </script>
```